# Problem with setting up dual monitor in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am following this below link for setting up the dual monitor.

```
"https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#How to setup a dual monitor"
```

If I uncheck "Same image in all monitors". The system tells me to log out and back in again. When I do that, there's the same image on both monitors and the checkbox was automatically checked(The old state.)

I did not find  any change in the xorg.conf file in my /etc/X11 folder too.

Can you please point me to solution for this problem?

Comment: Too much information is missing. Like your setup, your hardware etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related discussions on ubuntu forums :

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1597612
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9958943